# Change MS Office license / key without reinstalling?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-365

My company is currently leasing Office 2010 through Office 365.  We want to switch to SPLA licensing but the biggest concern we have is whether or not we will need to reinstall Office to change from the Office 365 subscription service to a Volume License model.

Is it possible to accomplish this without reinstalling Office?

Answer (score 2):

My inclination is that you will need to re-install office 2010 with appropriate media. However you can always try the following:

Ensure you have your existing product key stored safely.

Hit Winkey+R and enter appwiz.cpl.

This will bring up the add/remove programs dialogue. Select your Office 2010 installation and click on Change. One of the options presented is to change product key, select this and try your VL product key. If this fails then you will be looking at re-installation.

Answer (score 2):

I would think you need to re-install. You can do this to the masses by backaging up Office into an MSI and then deploying through GPO computer based policy.

I agree with @currySoup try and change the product key via add/remove programs with your volume license key first to see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

To change the license model or status of an existing Office install, I recommend using `ospp.vbs`, located in the Office install folder.  This allows the process to be scripted across an organization.

Office 365 is a "subscription" licensing product when working with `ospp.vbs`.

### List the current licensing status of Office products:

`ospp.vbs /dstatus`

### Add/Replace existing license key:

`ospp.vbs /inpkey:value` where `value` is KMS client key.

### Force activation via OSPP script:

`ospp.vbs /act`

[Technet Link for managing Volume Licensing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624350.aspx)